# I need to aggregate two collections based on userIds but couldn't manage it

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database-schema

I want to aggregate the collections (*Review and Account*) below but couldn't manage it properly so I needed to ask you guys.

Current **Review Collection** is written below

```
{
  lawyerId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId },
  reviews: [
    {
      userId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, unique: true },
      message: { type: String },
      rate: { type: Number },
      createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    },
  ],
}
```

If you recommend **Review Collection** can be refactored like this

```
{
  lawyerId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId },
  userId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId },
  message: { type: String },
  rate: { type: Number },
  createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
}
```

**Account Collection**

```
  {
    _id: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId} 
    email: { type: String, unique: true },
    firstName: { type: String },
    lastName: { type: String },
  },
```

**The expected result of fetching reviews**

```
{
 averageRate: 3.2,
 reviews: [
 {
  firstName: 'Jack',
  lastName: 'Harden',
  message: 'I dont like it',
  rate: 2, 
  createdAt: '2020-01-01T14:58:23.330+00:00'
 },
 {
  firstName: 'Takeshi',
  lastName: 'San',
  message: 'Thats nice',
  rate: 5, 
  createdAt: '2020-03-02T10:45:10.120+00:00'
 }
],
}
```

Comment: What is `lawyerId`? Is it an id reference from other collection? And you are trying to get `reviews` from particular `lawyerId`?

Comment: `lawyerId` comes with the request body and it is used to trying to get a single `review` from the **Review Collection**. So you said correct.

Comment: So `lawyerId` is the unique key for each Review document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this using an [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/).

You can view a live [demo here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7hvh85ATCh0), which allows you to run this query.

**The Query:**

```
// Assuming we are searching for an lawyerId of 3

db.review.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      lawyerId: 3
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "account",
      localField: "userId",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "user"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$user"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$lawyerId",
      averageRate: {
        $avg: "$rate"
      },
      reviews: {
        $push: {
          createdAt: "$createdAt",
          firstName: "$user.firstName",
          lastName: "$user.lastName",
          message: "$message",
          rate: "$rate"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {                    //   *******************************************
    $project: {        //   *******************************************
      _id: 0,          //   If you comment out/remove all of these lines
      averageRate: 1,  //   then the return also contains the 'lawyerId',
      reviews: 1       //   as '_id', which I would find useful...
    }                  //   *******************************************
  }                    //   *******************************************
])
```

**The Results:**

The query from above, using the data set from above, produces the following results:

```
[
  {
    "averageRate": 3.25,
    "reviews": [
      {
        "createdAt": ISODate("2015-02-28T00:00:00Z"),
        "firstName": "First",
        "lastName": "Uno",
        "message": "Message meh",
        "rate": 3
      },
      {
        "createdAt": ISODate("2015-02-28T00:00:00Z"),
        "firstName": "Second",
        "lastName": "Dos",
        "message": "Message blah",
        "rate": 4
      },
      {
        "createdAt": ISODate("2015-02-28T00:00:00Z"),
        "firstName": "First",
        "lastName": "Uno",
        "message": "Message foo",
        "rate": 4
      },
      {
        "createdAt": ISODate("2015-02-28T00:00:00Z"),
        "firstName": "Third",
        "lastName": "Tres",
        "message": "Message bar",
        "rate": 2
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**The Dataset:**

In [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net), you can build out databases with multiple collections, this explains the data structure:

```
db={             // <---- Database 'db'
  "account": [   // <---- Collection 'account'
    {
      _id: 21,
      email: "first.uno@gmail.com",
      firstName: "First",
      lastName: "Uno"
    },
    {
      _id: 22,
      email: "second.dos@yahoo.com",
      firstName: "Second",
      lastName: "Dos"
    },
    {
      _id: 23,
      email: "third.tres@hotmail.com",
      firstName: "Third",
      lastName: "Tres"
    }
  ],
  "review": [    // <---- Collection 'review'
    {
      lawyerId: 3,
      userId: 21,
      message: "Message meh",
      rate: 3,
      createdAt: ISODate("2015-02-28T00:00:00Z")
    },
    {
      lawyerId: 3,
      userId: 22,
      message: "Message blah",
      rate: 4,
      createdAt: ISODate("2015-02-28T00:00:00Z")
    },
    {
      lawyerId: 3,
      userId: 21,
      message: "Message foo",
      rate: 4,
      createdAt: ISODate("2015-02-28T00:00:00Z")
    },
    {
      lawyerId: 3,
      userId: 23,
      message: "Message bar",
      rate: 2,
      createdAt: ISODate("2015-02-28T00:00:00Z")
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I did a bit changes on this code and it works extremely nice! Thank you for your help and giving me the mongo playground link, I'm sure that will help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this pipeline to get all reviews from review collection:

```
db.reviews.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "accounts",
      localField: "userId",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "user"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$user"
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      "firstName": "$user.firstName",
      "lastName": "$user.lastName"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": null,
      "average_rate": {
        $avg: "$rate"
      },
      "reviews": {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: [
      "_id",
      "reviews._id",
      "reviews.user",
      "reviews.userId",
      "reviews.lawyerId"
    ]
  }
])
```

Results:

```
[
  {
    "average_rate": 3.5,
    "reviews": [
      {
        "createdAt": "Some Review Date",
        "firstName": "Jack",
        "lastName": "Harden",
        "message": "I dont like it",
        "rate": 2
      },
      {
        "createdAt": "Some Review Date",
        "firstName": "Takeshi",
        "lastName": "San",
        "message": "That's nice",
        "rate": 5
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

[Demo here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/azMB-Z8pBS-)

Comment: This code has worked and taught me new things about depths of mongo. Thank you so much sir!